# Number of connection to SQL Server in AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an ASP.Net MVC application that connect to SQL Server AWS RDS database. The ASP.net application gets data from SQL Server DB by processing excel file records.

That is, it reads each records from excel file create and make a API call to RDS to fetch data. The number of records in excel file is **directly proportional** to number of API calls to the SQL Server RDS. These calls are Asyn calls.

There is a performance issue, that is when number of records are increasing ( so as number of API calls). The required details are not getting fetched from the RDS. For low number of excel records, its working fine.

Is there any way to know, how many Asyn calls SQL server RDS can handle?  Or may be number of connections to RDS? or could there be any other issues?

Will it provide me a perfect error message , which will indicate, the number of connections are getting exceeded? Any Error code that can be checked from RDS end?

I believe, each API call is creating the connection. So, as API calls increasing the number of connection to the DB is also getting increased.

Note: I'm uploading the excel file, the processing starts once I click on upload file. Application hosted in EC2 and DB is RDS (SQL Server)

Hope I have explained this correctly. Thanks.

Comment: `sp_who` and `sp_who2` is the sql server way of of showing process list.

Comment: Sorry, Don't understand , how this can help? Are you recommending, when I upload the file, that time I can run this command to see how-many connections are getting created by the API calls?

Comment: it is equivalent to mysql’s show process list. You will monitor connections to debug